# AWS RDS MariaDB dropping connection after CREATE TABLE with CHECK followed by CREATE INDEX

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

I've spun up a fresh MariaDB T2 micro instance with all of the default settings (have observed same behavior on t3-micro and t3-small).

Running this script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `checked` INT NOT NULL,
    a_column VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_league PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT `ck_checked` CHECK (`checked` IN (0, 1, 2, 3))
);

CREATE INDEX ix_test_a_column ON test (a_column);
```

Causes this error:

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [08]: Could not connect to address=(host=database-1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

However, when I reconnect, the table `test` has been created, including the index.

No issue running the script on a local MariaDB 10.4 docker container, likewise no issue if I remove either of the `CONSTRAINT ... CHECK` or `CREATE INDEX`. If I replace the `CREATE INDEX` statement with `SELECT 1;` there is also no error.

Given that there is a difference in behavior between the docker db instance and the RDS instance, I'm hoping there might be some difference in configuration between the two that might explain the behavior on AWS and would appreciate any insight!

The server logs:

```
210215 7:38:57 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB-log
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=5
max_threads=68
thread_count=12
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 174615 K bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x2b48cfb35f88
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x2b48a41cbdd8 thread_stack 0x40000
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x5582a9cbc039]
mysys/stacktrace.c:270(my_print_stacktrace)[0x5582a970b75d]
sigaction.c:0(__restore_rt)[0x2b48a5211100]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(_ZN12Item_func_in7cleanupEv+0x31)[0x5582a981e141]
sql/item_cmpfunc.h:2414(Item_func_in::cleanup())[0x5582a94e7c9d]
sql/item.h:2183(Item::delete_self())[0x5582a94eadeb]
sql/sql_parse.cc:8104(mysql_parse(THD*, char*, unsigned int, Parser_state*, bool, bool))[0x5582a9535d1a]
sql/sql_parse.cc:1853(dispatch_command(enum_server_command, THD*, char*, unsigned int, bool, bool))[0x5582a9537655]
sql/sql_parse.cc:1368(do_command(THD*))[0x5582a9538a21]
sql/sql_connect.cc:1456(do_handle_one_connection(CONNECT*))[0x5582a960e34f]
sql/sql_connect.cc:1362(handle_one_connection)[0x5582a960e404]
pthread_create.c:0(start_thread)[0x2b48a5209dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x2b48a5514c9d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x2b48cfb6f620): CREATE INDEX ix_test_a_column ON test (a_column)
Connection ID (thread ID): 14
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```